# Redirect to edit page and then to detail page from apex

Tags: apex, pagereference

I am trying to deep clone the objects. I got the code for deep cloning from a blog http://christopheralunlewis.blogspot.com/2012/04/clone-plus-clone-salesforce-objects.html which is working perfectly for me. I have parent object as opportunity and child object as Line_item__c. After clicking clone button i want to be redirected to edit page. So i replaced

```
return new PageReference('/' + headClone.Id);
```

With:

```
return new PageReference('/' + headClone.Id + '/e');
```

But now it is redirecting me to home page on clicking save or cancel from edit page. Rather i would like to go detail page(which is a custom page) of newly cloned record on clicking save and old record detail page on clicking cancel.Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return new PageReference('/'+headClone.Id+'/e&retURL=%2Fapex/VFpageName?Id='+IdOfRecord
```